# When does the 301-redirected URL gets indexed?

Tags: google-search-console, 301-redirect, google-index

I had a page on my website like `example.com/dir/page` but now I have moved it to `example.com/page`.

The old URL 301-redirects to the new URL.

- When will it get updated in Google?
- I asked the bot to fetch it via Google Webmaster Tools, but when will it get effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should take up to 10-15 minutes for it to fetch the page, as indicated in [Google Webmaster Tools](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1352276?hl=en):

> 5.) Click **Fetch**. Google will fetch the URL you requested. It may take up
>   to 10 or 15 minutes for Fetch status to be updated.
>
> 6.) Once you see a Fetch status of "Successful", click **Submit to Index**, and then click one of the following:
>
> - To submit the individual URL to Google's index, select **URL** and click Submit. You can submit up to 500 URLs a week in this way.
> - To submit the URL and all pages linked from it, click **URL and all linked pages**. You can submit up to 10 of these requests a month

Pending that there isn't any crawling errors, it might take a few weeks for the old URL to drop off and new URL to show up, which you can check using `site:your-url.com`.

You should maintain the 301 redirect for quite some time after that for other search engines and incoming links.